# How can I make a view with an admin and user?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, postgresql

I'm making a crude in Django, and when I create it's shows and options depending if you are an administrator or a Jefe from the table. the administrator its from panel Django

```
class UsuarioCrear(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Usuarios
    form = Usuarios
    if user.is_superuser:
        fields = "__all__" 
        success_message = 'usuario creado correctamente !'
        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('leer')
    else:
        fields = ['nombre', 'correo', 'contraseña', 'cedula']
        success_message = 'usuario creado correctamente !'
        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('leer')
```

So, I try with an if asking if is a superuser show al fields and if not is a super user show an specific fields, but i got an error when i do that

This is the model view

```
class Usuarios(models.Model): 
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    rol = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=roles, default='seleccionar', blank=False)
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    contraseña = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
```

Comment: provide that error

Comment: NameError: name 'user' is not defined

Comment: is user a model name?

Comment: No, the model is Usuarios. 
Trying to do with the user from django panel administration

Comment: Then you must import it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply import it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as user
```

Now that error will solve.

And also try this:

```
if user.is_superuser():
        fields = "__all__" 
        success_message = 'usuario creado correctamente !'
        user.save()
        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('leer')
else:
        fields = ['nombre', 'correo', 'contraseña', 'cedula']
        success_message = 'usuario creado correctamente !'
        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('leer')
```

Comment: Yep, the problem it's gone, but the if it's not working well

when it gets into the if of the superuser its shows all the fields and thats it's correct, but when get into the else, still shows all fields.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. `User.is_superuser` doesn't make any sense as it tries to access an instance attribute.

Comment: @Selcuk I have given this answer based on error. and error is user is not defined. checkout the comment

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your first comment